# Office Add-in development: Styling an Inserted HTML table in Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I'm working on a Word Taskpane AddIn (Office.js). In this AddIn, I have a function to insert an HTML-table in the document. This is working fine, but now I want to style the table. It seems that is only possible using inline styling. I mean I cannot use any external-CSS file to style the insert HTML-table, which is kind of logical because in the Word document it would be impossible to reference such a css file? I just wonder if there are any other options, styling the table, like reference or apply a (builtin) style in Word for example. But I don't have a clue how I would do that in this case.

```
 function createReGeBoHtmlTable(result) {

    var srcArray = result.Sources;

    var table = "<table border='1' style='border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;width:100%'>";

    table += "<tr><th style='background-color:#FF0000;text-align:left'>Onderdeel</th><th>Bevinding</th><th>Informatiebron</th></tr>";

    $.each(result.Values, function (i, item) {
        console.log(item);

        var src = "";
        if (item.sources) {

            $.each(item.sources, function (j, source) {
                src = src + srcArray[source].name + '<sup>' + source.toString() + '<sup> \n';
            })
        };

        table += "<tr><td style='width:40%'><strong>" + item.title + "</strong></td><td>" + ((item.value == 'null') ? "" : item.value) + "</td><td>" + src + "</td></tr>";
    });

    table += "</table>";
    insertHtmlTable(table);
```

This is the code I use to create the table

```
    function insertHtmlTable(htmlTable) {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var thisDocument = context.document;

        var range = thisDocument.getSelection();
        range.insertHtml(htmlTable, 'End');
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            ;
            console.log('Added Table.');
        });
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
}
```

Any ideas are welcome.

UPDATE

In the meantime, I have found another way for developing an AddIn. This gives me also the possibility for using styles on a table. I also found a very useful option for developing Add In ([Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab). I generate my Add in now using [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator).

Therefore this question can be closed!